# How to regain access to Google after phone is found?

Tags: google, lost-phone

I lost my Android phone but after a few days someone returned it to me. Unfortunately, in the mean time I had blocked my SIM, and blocked my Google and Facebook accounts from using that phone device. Is there any way I can unblock the accounts? I need a phone in which I can check my email.

Comment: Why Have'nt you installed Android Device Manager on your device? If you've installed it earlier, maybe none of this would have happened. It's going to be a little tricky getting everything back.

Comment: Are you able to unlock the device? If so remove the previously added google account and add it again in the accounts section of your settings page. See if you can login into the blocked google account and may be google will ask to verify the account and you can do so and get access back to your account.

Comment: *"I had blocked my SIM, and blocked my google and facebook accounts"* -- What do you mean by blocked the Google and Facebook accounts? Did you contact them to do so for you (unlikely), or did you go to respective websites and deactivate the accounts? I need to know can you log-in using their website on Desktop?